# Valid target for goto statement

Tags: c++, goto

I was doing a C++ test and one question puzzeled me a lot.

What is the valid target for `goto` statement:

1. `&Label;`
2. `:LABEL`
3. `<LABEL>`
4. `Label:`
5. `:Label;`

I think `;` has nothing to do with `goto` statement. It is a sequence point.
So the only one answer would be 5 but `<>` are not permitted in the label name,
I'm very confused.

Comment: What does your introductory book tell you about the syntax for a `goto` label? (Apart from "don't use `goto`", obviously.)

Comment: You're right, goto is evil. But for some reason, I have found it used in Gdiplus and Windows header files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for the target of goto is

```
4) Label:
```

Though it would be more correctly to say that the target of a goto statement is a label itself because according to the C++ Standard (6.1 Labeled statement)

> The only use of an identifier label is as the target of a goto

On the other hand the target of a goto statement is a labeled statement.:)

So in my opinion the question is not clear whether it asks about the syntax of writing a label or what is the target.:).

I suppose that the question about the syntax.

Comment: It seems that i'm mixing the word target with word argument?

Comment: @zulunation I can say nothing about what you are mixing.:)

Comment: I thought that target for goto statement means what is going after goto keyword. Forinstance consider the example: goto mylabel; Here mylabel is target.

Comment: @zulunation  In this case neither variant shown by you is valid.